# how to append a function variable to an object string in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, object, form-submit

```
function GenKeyForm(FormNum){
    document.GenNewKey+FormNum.submit();
}
```

I have multiple forms within a php page. each form has been given an id and each respective submit link the same id within this javascript call GenKeyForm(ID).

How do i add FormNum to the object call document.GenNewKey.submit? I know in php you can append variables and strings using . however I have no idea for javascript.

the php for the form name is:

```
echo '<form action="#" name="GenNewKey'.$num.'" id="GenNewKey'.$num.'" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dot notation requires you to use *identifiers* for each property name. If you want to use *strings* you have to use [square bracket notation](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/).

```
document["GenNewKey" + FormNum].submit();
```

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated. clearly I have a lot more to learn about javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
function GenKeyForm(FormNum){
    document.getElementById("GenNewKey"+FormNum).submit();
}
```